# How and why did “AM”/"PM” come into play, as opposed to “a.m.”/“p.m.”?

Tags: history, time, acronyms

From several sources, [including english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/22784/10307), one should write 3 p.m. instead of 3 PM.

How did the all-capitals variant appear, **and especially why**? Is it because with typewriters and in terminals, `PM` uses half as much space than `a.m.`?

Comment: I think you have found already found your answer: _'Because the initials in question are of Latin origin ("post meridian"/"ante meridian")'_

Comment: You should probably change your question to why "AM"/"PM" came into play (as opposed to "a.m."/"p.m.") to avoid running the risk of having your question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Why? It's two characters less to type. People write _w8_, _4_ and _r_ to avoid typing too many characters, so why bother with the extra dots? In many situations, people want their message to be conveyed, and they don't really care if someone wants to judge their message as if it were a literary work. Why the capitals? I guess to indicate, in absence of the dots, that it _is_ an abbreviation (you could confuse _am_ with the verb).  Why do these things appear? Because people find them easy, it turns out they are perfectly understandable, so there is hardly any reason to use the less-easy way.

Comment: "The terms "a.m." and "p.m." are abbreviations of the Latin *ante meridiem* (before midday) and *post meridiem* (after midday). Depending on the style guide referenced, the abbreviations "AM" and "PM" are variously written in small capitals ("ᴀᴍ" and "ᴘᴍ"), uppercase letters ("AM" and "PM"), or lowercase letters ("am" and "pm")." Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Typography

Comment: "one should write 3 p.m. instead of 3 PM" -- not necessarily.

Comment: "why" questions have almost no meaning.

Comment: No, one should write 15:00 instead of 3 PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the use of AM and PM increased during the early days of computer systems.  Back in character-mode days, one had to be especially parsimonious with screen and page "real-estate". Uppercase AM and PM without punctuation used only two characters, and there was also no space between the time value and the AM or PM value.  It was often common to see all uppercase.

But [6pm](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=6PM%2C6%20p.m.%2C6pm%2C6p.m.&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C6PM%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C6%20p.m.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C6pm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C6p.m.%3B%2Cc0) seems to be on the ascendant.

Comment: In the early computer days there was no "a" or "p" or "m".

Answer (score -1):

The all-capitals variant is probably borrowed from AM/FM radio. (These are abbreviations for *amplitude modulation* and *frequency modulation*}